# Spring resource class loading from an external folder

Tags: spring, resources, message

I have a spring project name: SpringExample‬

the Directory Structure:

[image]

the locale.xml for the spring :

```
<bean id="customerService" class="com.mkyong.customer.services.CustomerService" />

<bean id="messageSource"
    class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource">
    <property name="basename">
        <value>\SpringExample\conf‬\messages</value>
    </property>
</bean>
```

the code for CustomerService:

```
 package com.mkyong.customer.services;


    public class CustomerService implements MessageSourceAware
    {
        private MessageSource messageSource;

        public void setMessageSource(MessageSource messageSource) {
            this.messageSource = messageSource;
        }

        public void printMessage(){
            String name = messageSource.getMessage("customer.name", 
                    new Object[] { 28, "http://www.mkyong.com" }, Locale.US);
            System.out.println("Customer name (English) : " + name);

    }
```

the code for the app class (the main class):

```
package com.mkyong.common;

import java.util.Locale;

import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;

import com.mkyong.customer.services.CustomerService;

public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(
                new String[] { "locale.xml" });

        // get the message resource inside context
        String name = context.getMessage("customer.name", new Object[] { 28,
                "http://www.mkyong.com" }, Locale.US);
        System.out.println("Customer name (English) : " + name);


        // get the message resource inside the bean
        CustomerService cust = (CustomerService) context
                .getBean("customerService");
        cust.printMessage();
    }
}
```

But it fails to bundle the proprtie file, because it isn't in the package.
i get the exception:

> WARNING: ResourceBundle [\SpringExample\conf?\messages] not found for
>   MessageSource: Can't find bundle for base name
>   \SpringExample\conf?\messages, locale en_US

how can i get it to bundle with external folder resource like in my example?

Comment: no. i don't want it as a resource file, i did it using maven resources

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make the `conf` directory a maven resource directory (maven build helper plugin) or move the files from `conf` to `src\main\resources`. Then modify the `ResourceBundleMessageSource` to load the messages form classpath root, because `src\main\resources` correspond to the classpath root.

```
<bean id="messageSource"
    class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource">
    <property name="basename">
        <value>messages</value>
    </property>
</bean>
```

*Attention: If you use `ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource` instead of `ResourceBundleMessageSource` then you have to use the prefix `classpath:` for the `basename` propertz value (`classpath:messages`)*

Comment: I don't think you have to put "classpath:" in the value tag of property. [ResourceBundleMessageSource](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/api/org/springframework/context/support/ResourceBundleMessageSource.html#setBasename%28java.lang.String%29) resolves resources from the classpath without the classpath prefix.

Comment: @Justin Wrobel: You are right, I allways have trouble with the different syntax for `ResourceBundleMessageSource` and `ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource` -- I corrected the answer